# Is Determinant of 2x2 inverse matrix equal to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant, inverse

Let's say $A=$ $
\begin{pmatrix}
a & c \\
b & d \\
\end{pmatrix}$, then inverse of $A$,  $A^{-1}=$ $\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}
d & -c \\
-b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Regardless of what matrix A is, if it's square matrix, we can show the fact that
$$det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{det(A)}$$ 
Since, $$det(A^{-1}A)=1$$ $$det(A^{-1}A)=det(A)det(A^{-1}).$$

And If we consider the given form of A $$det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$$

However, through the defined notation of determinant, we can also derive the value of $A^{-1}$
$$det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{vmatrix}
d & -c \\
-b & a \\
\end{vmatrix}$$

$$=1$$
which result seems contradicts result above

What I'd done wrong? I kept check it over and over again, still I end up here.

With considering what matrix transformations could geometrically mean, I believe the result  $det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{ad-bc}$ should be the truth.

Answer (score 5):

Note that$$\det\begin{bmatrix}\lambda a&\lambda b\\\lambda c&\lambda d\end{bmatrix}=\lambda^2\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: oMg. wHaT hAve IVe DONE!
thank you so much..

Comment: Yup, $\operatorname{det}$ is a multilinear application (here bilinear). Don't forget to accept José's answer! ;)